# Implementing a high score in an android app

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want my app to display the top 3 results of the high score, the score of the last session and the score that's one rank higher and one rank lower than the last session. When there's a gap between the result of rank 3 and the next entry I want to display a [...] placeholder.

I want to allow scrolling. If the user scrolls upwards the score two places about the last session score becomes visible. At the moment I don't know how to implement this.
I don't want to load all the data at once but at a as needed basis when the user scrolls.

How do I set this up in the most efficient way?

Comment: Scrolling through what? You list 6 scores, which should (1) be easy to fetch, and (2) fit in a single "window". Am I missing something?

Comment: "I don't want to load all the data at once but at a as needed basis when the user scrolls." This is just local scores?

Comment: How many are you going to store total? I wouldn't worry about loading in 100 rows for example.

Comment: I'd load the data in a ListView (possibly during a Splash Screen, just to hide the lag behind an intro graphics / music). Once and for all. An AsyncTask is your best friend: in `onPostExecute()`, run the Main Activity or load the Main Screen Fragment.